# Simple Meteor Method Jasmine Test not working

Tags: javascript, meteor, jasmine, velocity

I'm trying to test Meteor methods using Jasmine but getting a constant blue dot as opposed to a red/green one and the following errors:

```
(STDERR) connections property is deprecated. Use getConnections() method
(STDERR) [TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined]
```

My methods are located under `lib/methods.js` and the method I'm trying to test is as follows:

```
Meteor.methods({
    copy_on_write_workout: function(day) {
        if (!Meteor.userId()) {
            throw new Meteor.Error("not-authorized");
        }
        var date    = day_to_date(day, 0);
        var workout = Workouts.findOne({
            day: day,
            owner: Meteor.userId(),
            current_week: true
        });

        // not completed in the past. no need to copy it
        if (workout.completed.length == 0 ||
            (workout.completed.length == 1 &&
            workout.completed.last().getTime() == date.getTime())) {
                return;
        }

        var new_workout = workout;
        if (workout.completed.last().getTime() == date.getTime()) {
            new_workout.completed = [date.getTime()];
            Workouts.update(workout._id, {$pop: {completed: 1}});
        } else {
            new_workout.completed = [];
        }

        Workouts.update(workout._id, {$set: {current_week: false}});

        delete new_workout["_id"];
        Workouts.insert(new_workout);
    }
});
```

Here is my simple test under `tests/jasmine/server/unit/method.js`:

```
describe('workouts', function() {
    it("copy_on_write_workout simple test", function() {

        spyOn(Workouts, 'findOne');

        Meteor.call('copy_on_write_workout', "Monday");

        expect(Workouts.findOne).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
});
```

Both `sanjo:jasmine` and `velocity:html-reporter` have been installed and are included in my packages. Is there any additional setup required before I can get this to work? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor method calls take a callback function as the last arguement as described here https://forums.meteor.com/t/use-meteor-call-with-jasmine-doesnt-work/6702/2.

I fixed my tests by simply changing it to:

```
describe('workouts', function() {
    it("copy_on_write_workout when never completed", function() {
        spyOn(Workouts, 'findOne');
        spyOn(Meteor, 'userId').and.returnValue(1);

        Meteor.call('copy_on_write_workout', "Monday", function(err, result) {
            expect(Workouts.findOne).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
    });
});
```

Furthermore, I added `spyOne(Meteor, 'userId').and.returnValue(1)` so that checking if the user has been logged in passes.